# Camera app running in background (Multitasking) IOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, background-process, multitasking

I want to take a photo once every 5 minutes but it is essential the app is in the background. for completely legitimate reasons. 
Is this possible?

I am willing to go to all ends of the earth to achieve my goal, is it possible a corporate entity can achieve this if a public can't. Is there such thing as special permission from apple in app design?

Comment: No this is not possible, apple does not allow app running in the background to access the camera. Maybe on a jailbroke device this might be possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture images in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736189/capture-images-in-the-background)

Comment: Clement, the link you referred to, is that taking photos with the app he is referring too minimised?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't access the camera while in app is running in the background.

[Allowed long-running background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23)

Comment: is there any possible way i can achieve this, i plan on using this app in a schooling environment and thus the ipad will be linked to the schools ipad program, can they do this?

Comment: @LucasLister Not that I know. Maybe by using some private API's, but then Apple won't allow it in the App Store.

Comment: Thats okay I dont think I am aiming for an app store POS. Could you link me on more info about private APIs?